# AngularJS auto check once a while

Tags: php, html, angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services

I am new to Angular and had a request to do the following:

1. User creates an account(Or any other activities).
2. If user has not used account, lets say a week.
3. I need to send them a notification. (I don't need to do this until no.1 and 2 is sorted)

Here are my thoughts:

1. Save the date/time when user has created account (add date/time to all activities).
2. Use **something** that constantly loops through all accounts.
3. Check if activities in each account has not been used, maybe use a counter or bool to check if they had or not. If they had a return of true then do not compare date/time otherwise do so.

We are using php and ajax for our back-end scripting.
Can you guys tell me what **something** is used for auto checking in angular and if you have a better solution can you share it. Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like something you wanna do server-side and not in angular. How should the webapp know the accounts?

Comment: what you mean with notification?? an email?? an in-app notification like popup?? in the first case you need a php cronjob that check for user accounts, in the second case you need both a php cronjob and a script inside your app that check for notifications.

Comment: In nodejs you will want to use an [interval](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_arg)

Comment: Is there a way to pass a token with a timer to an account/activity?

Comment: 3. I need to send them a notification. -> this stage is not necessary yet.

Comment: One way to do this would be with expiration of sessions, I've read of people achieving scheduled tasks on the front end using session expiration. Tbh it seems like a server side job though I agree. A scheduled Db query. Are you on a MEAN stack?

Comment: No we are using Amazon, php, AngularJS, NodeJS but not sure if ExpressJS is used.

Comment: I have used cron jobs to call my php files at fixed times.